# How to merge rows and add the data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R for example:-

```
location date        data

India    21-01-19    23
India    22-01-19    21
USA      21-01-19    33
USA      21-01-19    35
```

I want to merge the rows so as to get

```
location  data

India     44
USA       68
```

Is there an R function or a way in R to do the above? My original data frame is very large and I don't need date column but just data for the location

EDIT:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("India", 
"Usa"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("21-01-19", 
"22-01-19"), class = "factor"), value = c(21, 23, 33, 35)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(location = c("India", "India", "USA", "USA"), 
                 date = c("21-01-19", "22-01-19", "21-01-19", "21-01-19"), 
                 data = c(23, 21, 33, 35))

df %>%
  select(-c(date)) %>% 
  group_by(location) %>% 
  tally(data)

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   location     n
#   <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 India       44
# 2 USA         68
```

Answer (score 0):

using dplyr  :

```
library(dplyr)

 data<- data.frame(location = c("India", "India", "USA", "USA"), 
                 date = c("21-01-19", "22-01-19", "21-01-19", "21-01-19"), 
                 value = c(23, 21, 33, 35))


# calculation:

 data %>% group_by(location) %>% summarise(value=sum(value))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  location value
  <fct>    <dbl>
1 India       44
2 Usa         68
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Input = (
  'location date data
   India 21-01-19 23
   India 22-01-19 21
   USA 21-01-19 33
   USA 21-01-19 35')
df = read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T)


res <- as.data.frame(cbind(by(df$data,list(df$location),sum)))
res$location <- rownames(res)
colnames(res)[1] <- 'data'
res <- res[,c(2,1)]
rownames(res) <- c()

res

  location data
1    India   44
2      USA   68
```